# Парсинг txt-файлов. Вытаскивание части выражения из регулярки?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Есть лог-файлы, каждый из которых соответствует определённой дате. И каждый содержит несколько тысяч строк. В файлах есть сообщения, у каждого сообщения есть время отправки.
Мне нужно посчитать количество сообщений за каждый час.

Я считываю текстовый файл построчно. И время отправки могу найти регуляркой:

```
    Regex regexMessageTime = new Regex(@"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} <#\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}>[.]+:");
```

Что соответствует выражению: "00:00:00 <#00:00:00> текст:"
Количество сообщений в день я считаю просто по количеству совпадений с регуляркой.
Но как посчитать сообщения за каждый час?
Полагаю, нужно вытаскивать время сообщения в переменную DateTime, находить ближайшее сообщение к началу часа, т. е. к 00:00:00, и считать, пока не будет найден следующий час, т. е. ближайшее время к 01:00:00.
[Похожая проблема - из строки "00:00:00 <#00:00:00> текст:" нужно будет вытаскивать "текст" и в отдельную таблицу заносить.]

В правильном ли направлении мыслю?
Стоит искать способ вытащить время из регулярки? Или просто "вручную" парсить каждую строку и доставать время?
Как наиболее экономно это делать? Количество строк наверное может достигнуть и 15 тысяч, но более вероятно, что будет держаться между 5000 и 10000.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А где у вас в "00:00:00 <#00:00:00> текст:" тот самый час? Первые две цифры? Тогда регулярка совсем не нужна и проблема решается гораздо проще.

Comment: А что у вас означает `[.]+` там действительно точки после времени или вы имели ввиду произвольные символы и тогда квадратные скобки не нужны ... А вообще вы можете в регулярке выделить часы с помощью круглых скобок `(\d{2})` и они будут у вас в переменных захвата регулярных выражений (не знаю, где они в c#, но они должны быть)

Comment: @Mike, точка - это произвольные символы, а скобки действительно не нужны, да. Про переменные - очень смутно помню, что было что-то такое, но почитал и не разобрался с ними, поэтому решил описать задачу в целом - и, как оказалось, я не додумался до способа проще, хотя было даже 2. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего просто считать список и перевести его в нормальную структуру данных (например, назовём её `LogEntry`). Имея список этих самых `LogEntry`, можно сгруппировать по часам, например, при помощи LINQ:

```
entries.GroupBy(e => e.Date.Hour)
```

Comment: Т. е. время всех-всех сообщений записать в структуру? Она получится такая гигантская, способ кажется не слишком экономным.

Comment: Благодарю за версию.

Comment: Гигантская? Это порядка мегабайта? В одной строке текста вряд ли поместится гигантская структура. Тем более, если вы хотите дальше каким-то образом обрабатывать текст, структура вам пригодится.

Comment: Ну, может быть погорячился, значений просто будет очень дофига, а при втором варианте всё куда проще. / А считывать данные в структуру? Брать символы с заданных позиций? Пока не знаю, теоретически структура может пригодиться, но пока не знаю как - кое-какие другие данные буду подсчитывать, при их подсчёте вряд ли понадобится знать время.

Comment: @Max: Смотрите. Если вам и правда нужно _только_ количество сообщений в час, лучше решение с символами в строке. Пока вам не нужно вытаскивать много информации, тот подход лучше. Если вам нужно будет делать что-то нетривиальное, то разбор строки в экземпляр класса будет более правильной опцией. Вы в любой момент можете переключиться с одной стратегии на другую.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "нетривиальным" ? Если нетрудно, можете пояснить, зачем разбирать строку в экземпляр класса, почему это может быть выгоднее? И обрисовать в общих чертах схему? Плохо представляю, опыта у меня еще мало (как несложно догадаться). Даже если не пригодится сейчас, не исключено, что пригодится в будущем, да и просто интересно.

Comment: Ну, если вам нужна только дата, это просто, и вам не нужно считывать всю строку. А вот если после даты записано ещё, например, тип сообщения, его важность как число, текст ошибки, если есть, имя модуля, отправившего сообщения, и всё такое, и вы захотите найти, скажем, со вчерашний день все тексты ошибок ошибки от модуля X важностью не менее 50, вам не обойтись без полного разбора структуры.

Comment: Можно считать, что у меня три типа строк, один - строка без времени, второй и третий - сообщения со временем от разных модулей. Отличие в том, что третий тип - информационное про онлайн/оффлайн модуля. Первый тип практически нужен только в самом начале. При разных условиях буду считать сообщения второго и третьего типа, или их части. При этом нужно знать время, вытаскивать имя модуля, тип сообщения (2/3).

Comment: В таком случае, похоже, структура всё-таки нужна, но как её организовать, подскажите? Экземпляр класса - это вы про структуру говорили? Учитывая, что будет много значений времени, получается, нужен массив структур? И тогда каждый элемент массива соответствует сообщению. Или одна структура, в которой будет несколько массивов? Первый вариант более логичный вроде и больше похож на ваше описание.

Comment: @Max: Структура данных — в вашем случае класс — по идее должна соответствовать одной строке лог-файла. И этих структур нужен массив, или лучше `List<...>`.

Comment: Почему лучше List? "В моём случае класс" ? Так всё-таки структура или класс?

Comment: @Max: `List<>` потому, что в отличие от массива его размер не нужно знать заранее, можно добавлять элементы динамически. Массив — вообще очень неудобная структура данных, не нужен практически никогда. // По поводу структуры, я имел в виду структуру данных в общем смысле, а не конкретно `struct`. Думаю, проще будет взять класс.

Comment: Хм, а почему проще класс? Я-то уже думал на структуре остановиться. Простите за много вопросов.

Comment: @Max: В C# отличие структуры от класса довольно серьёзное. Например, структура всегда копируется при передаче в другой метод, в отличие от класса. Поэтому если вы отдадите структуру на обработку в другой метод, то этот метод будет менять копию структуры, а не оригинал. Вообще, различий между ними довольно много, стоит почитать об этом. Наверняка об этом был вопрос раньше, загляните в поиск.

Comment: Я знал, что различий много, хотя и весьма плохо помню их, честно говоря. Может и правда не задал бы этот вопрос, если бы помнил. / Хорошо, огромное вам спасибище! :)

Comment: @Max: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Берете из каждой строки первые два символа, atoi (или что там с C# для преобразования строки в число) на них и получаете целое число, которое соответствует часу. Regexp не нужен, для статистики достаточно массива на 24 элемента, которые увеличиваются если сообщение попало в конкретный час.

Comment: Спасибо, пожалуй, так действительно гораздо проще будет.

Comment: @Max а также существенно быстрее.